# Paypal : execute script when the donation is done

Tags: php, sql, paypal

How can I execute a script **PHP** that give one point on a **SQL database** when the donation is done ?

I have a page for donation. Created with : https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/

**For example** a page with the XXXXXXXXXXXXX ID.

```
<a href="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?
hosted_button_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&cmd=_s-xclick"></a>
```

When the user click, He is redirected on a PayPal page, for do the donation.

**For example** :

1. The redirect success page is : *www.test.com/sucess.php* **->** give one point.
2. And the fail page is : *www.test.com/error.php*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [PayPal IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).  That's what you want to use to automate post-transaction procedures.

Comment: Yes I created a listener IPN page, but It didn't work.

Comment: Ok, well you must have something incorrect within it.  IPN works great.

Comment: Yes, IPN works with any PayPal transaction.  I have [this old IPN template](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-ipn-template) you could install.  Out of the box it will receive your IPNs successfully and save the data to MySQL tables.

Comment: Okey, I'll try again. Thanks you !